# Match formula, where the criteria are the same

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make a list over the offers we've gotten on some properties we're selling. I have used the match formula combined with index, to list investors, dates etc. The problem is, that some offers are the same, and then the formula shows me the same investor and date

[An example on the list I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt1Sl.jpg)

My formula looks like this: `=INDEX($S$28:$S$30;MATCH(V28;$R$28:$R$30;0))`

Can I make it ignore the first, and give me the second result or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a pivot table with Offer, Date and Investor as rows, and no values. Change report layout to "tabular view". You could easily extend this to show more information too. I have included a column for "property" which you can use as a filter, for example:

[image: Possible solution using PivotTable]

When you add more data, just refresh and job done. Probably want to sort the PT by offers in descending order. Also, as a general rule I would start with the source data formatted as a table so the PivotTable will automatically pick up new rows.

Comment: So simple, and yet I couldn't think of it. I have an overlook page, where a dropdown controls which property is shown on all other sheets. Therefore the property is not that important. The problem now is, that the list of offers doesn't change automatically now, because I have to refresh the Pivot. Any tricks to make it easier, than shifting sheet and refreshing every time I choose a new property from the dropdown?

Comment: I made a macro to automatically update the pivot, when there were changes on the front page. Thank you very much for your help